# How can I create class “Item” before the class “Transaction” exist, with FactoryBot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, tdd, factory-bot, minitest

I was wondering if anyone can help. I am receiving an error message in the terminal saying `Validation failed: Item must exist`. I think that happens because FactoryBot is trying to create a Transaction class before the Item class, I think, I have to find a way to make the Item exist first before the Transaction, I tried many different ways, but had no success so far. `optional: true` is not an option, appreciate any help.
ps: this is my first time I am asking a help in StackOverflow so apologies if something is not right in my post.

Down below you can find 3 files, if you want to see other files let me know.

```
require "test_helper"

class PurchasesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  describe "#index" do
    let(:user_id) { Faker::Internet.uuid }
    let(:payload) { { user_id:, account_number: 1 } }
    let(:purchase_count) { 3 }

    before do
      WebMock.stub_request(:get, "#{ENV['IDENTITY_SERVICE_URL']}/users/#{user_id}")
             .to_return(status: 200, body: user_response(user_id:), headers: jsonapi_headers)         

      create(:as_asset)
      purchase_count.times do
        create(:purchase, user_id: 1)
      end
    end
    it "returns successful response" do
      get purchases_url, headers: authorization_header(payload)
      assert_response :success
      assert_match(/"total":#{purchase_count}/, response.body)
    end

    context "when unauthorized" do
      it "returns unauthorized response" do
        get purchases_url
        assert_response :unauthorized
      end
    end
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :purchase do
    user_id { Faker::Internet.uuid }
    for_as_asset

    trait :for_gasset do
      association :item, factory: :gasset
    end

    trait :for_as_asset do
      association :item, factory: :as_asset
    end

    after(:create) do |object|
      create(:transaction, purchase_id: object.id, purchase_type: "Purchase")
    end
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :transaction do
    item_id { 4 }
    item_type { "AsAsset" }
    user_id { Faker::Internet.uuid }
    purchase_ref { "Purchase reference" }
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you actually need to use `after(:create)`? Can't you just use a assocation? https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/main/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations

Comment: Additionally `WebMock.stub_request(:get, "#{ENV['IDENTITY_SERVICE_URL']}/users/#{user_id}")...` is pretty stinky. You should abstract away the details of mocking authentication out of your specs so that you're not repeating yourself or leaking the implementation details all over. I would do this with a helper module that you include into your integration/system specs.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback max! Using associations does not change anything really, terminal shows same error message. Regarding your second comment, will definetley refactor in future as you suggested, it makes sense.

Comment: Thats it @max, I nailed it! Adding "item_id: object.item_id, item_type: object.item_type" inside the block statement of purchase factory worked in a beautifully green color in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question:

Added `item_id: object.item_id, item_type: object.item_type` inside the block statement of purchase factory.

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :purchase do
    for_gasset
    after(:create) do |object|
      create(:transaction, user_id: object.user_id, item_id: object.item_id, item_type: object.item_type, purchase_id: object.id, purchase_type: "Purchase")
    end

    trait :for_gasset do
      association :item, factory: :gasset
    end

    trait :for_as_asset do
      association :item, factory: :as_asset
    end

    user_id { Faker::Internet.uuid }
  end
end
```